# Group By a particular column

Tags: algorithm, scala

New to scala, having tough time around maps and lists, its not the same as java say I have a scala function which gives me the records from a database which are in the following format with columns

```
id owner_id type_id name value
```

Let's name this as a

```
case class Row(id: UUID, ownerId: UUID, typeId: UUID, name: String, value: String)
```

Now I want to write a function which takes these rows as input and spits out a map in Scala which looks like the following, can someone please help me with a function

```
{
  "owner": "ownerId",
  "configurations": {
    "type1": {
      "name1": "value1",
      "name2": "value2"
    },
    "type2": {
      "name3": "value3",
      "name4": "value4"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a json object not a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this result type

```
case class Data(owner: UUID, configurations: Map[UUID, Map[String, String]])
```

I haven't tested this, but this might work to get `configurations` field. Since there are multiple rows, I'm not sure how `owner` field can be populated with one value.

```
def convert(rows: Seq[Row]): Data =
  Data(owner = ???,
       configurations = rows.groupMapReduce(_.typeId)(r => Map(r.name -> r.value))(_ ++ _))
```

This uses the [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) function in `Seq`, which will first group all rows based on `typeId`. It'll then map each row `r` to a `Map` with one entry `name` to `value`. `++` will then combine all these small `Map`s.